# How to change active file in external process?

Tags: c#, process

What I'm trying to do is use SolidWorks' eDrawings (as an example) to open a specified .dwg file that the user selects from a list my application generates.

I am able to do this without issue, but what I'd like to do at this point is, if the eDrawings process is already running, change the .dwg it is displaying to the new one the user has selected.

I already have the Process object for the eDrawings application, and I have used process.CloseMainWindow() successfully on it, so I know my app is targeting the correct process.

I just need to know how to instruct it to change files.  Is this going to be something specific to eDrawings (and/or unavailable from the .NET framework itself) ?

Maybe something like

```
Process myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("eDrawings")[0];
myProcess.CurrentFile = myNewFile;
```

Can this be done?

EDIT:

For emphasis on the solution I seek, I want the eDrawings program to load the new .dwg file *without* closing and opening a new instance of itself.

The point of trying to do this is to get around the excessive load times every time the application opens.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly and you try to let other processes to access your main application process you might want to read about Interop Marshaling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3.aspx